# Load multiple comments for different events in Django view

Tags: python, django

In my recent project, I was trying to do a website to make people hold events, while others could comment the events.

I want to show all the events hosted by the user in his/her profile page, I created `EventsBoard` model to store event details and `Comment` model to store all the comments.

```python
class Comment(models.Model):
  text = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  for_event = models.ForeignKey(
    EventsBoard,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='comments'
  )
  author = models.ForeignKey(
    "user_extend.UserExtend",
    on_delete = models.CASCADE,
    related_name='comment_author'
  )
  rate = IntegerRangeField(min_value=1, max_value=10)
  date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.text
```

and I have the `view.py` as follow.

```python
def profile_view(requests, id, *args, **kwargs):
  obj = UserExtend.objects.get(id=id)

  activities = EventsBoard.objects.filter(host=obj).filter(event_type='activity')
  projects = EventsBoard.objects.filter(host=obj).filter(event_type='project')
  personal_projs = EventsBoard.objects.filter(host=obj).filter(event_type='personal')
  
  context = {
    'user': obj,
    'activities': activities,
    'projects': projects,
    'personal_projs': personal_projs
  }
  return render(requests, 'profile.pug', context)
```

But since one can host lots of events, I am wondering how could I load the comment model to the `view.py` to bind the event object with comment objects.

**Edit**

This is the template I used for the profile activity part `profile.pug`, and I wish to load the comment part as follow code.

```pug
#activities
  #activity-cards-panel
    {% for activity in activities %}
    #activity-card
      #activity-img
      #activity-date {{ actvity.event_date }}
      h4#activity-title {{ activity.title }}
      #activity-rate
        p {{ activity.rate }}
      #activity-character
        p {{ activity.character }}
      
      // I want to load the comment as something like this
      {% for comment in comments %}
      #activity-comments-panel
        #activity-comment
          #activity-participant-img(src="{{ comment.author.img.url }}")
          p#activity-participant-name {{ comment.author.name }}
          p#activity-participant-comment {{ comment.text }}
          #activity-participant-rate 
            p {{ comment.rate }}
      {% empty %}
      p No comment yet
      {% endfor %}

    {% empty %}
    p It seems like he does not host any activity...
    {% endfor %}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show us the templates and expected result

Comment: Try to use {% for comment in activity.comments %} in your template

Comment: @zanuda Thanks a lot!!! That just what I need. But if I just use `{% for comment in activity.comments %} `, it would raise `TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable`, so I modified it with `{% for comment in activity.comments.all %}` and it works very well. Much appreciated for your help!

Comment: Exactly, I forgot to add `all`) I was glad to help. P.S. think about changing the `related_name` for `author` field to a more appropriate one. For example, comments too.